# Retrofit POST request to Spring Boot service

Tags: java, post, spring-boot, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for post request to Spring Boot service but always is called failure Callback method. This is my simplified code:

Spring Boot service (Controller):

```
@RestController
public class ServController {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public Boolean signUpUser(@RequestBody User user)
   {

      return true;
   }
}
```

My client interface:

```
public interface ChainApi {

    public static final String USER_PATH = "/user";

    @POST(USER_PATH)
    public void signUpUser(@Body User user, Callback<Boolean> callback);
}
```

Async POST request:

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(12);
user.setName(nameEtx.getText().toString());
user.setEmail(emailEtx.getText().toString());
user.setPassword(passwordEtx.getText().toString());

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constant.URL_LOCALHOST)
            .build();

ChainApi service = restAdapter.create(ChainApi.class);

service.signUpUser(user, new Callback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Boolean aBoolean, Response response) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Succesfull");

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage()); // 400 Bad Request

    }
});
```

This is my User class(POJO):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "additionalProperties"})
public class User {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // methods
}
```

NOTES: I am developing in Android and when make manual POST request from Postman I get 200 OK.
In addition I get in logcat message: **400 Bad Request**

Comment: Post the error that you're getting

Comment: Updated my post in the final part

Comment: Sounds like your server doesn't like something from your request, perhaps something missing in it.  Take a look at the logs on the server, those will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I resolved the issue. I was able to get the full server response, this a part: "exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field \"additionalProperties\". Now my question is why retrofit takes this field if it has annotations @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "additionalProperties"}) and @JsonIgnore.

Comment: You should update your question with those details.  I've added an answer, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit uses GSON as its default `Converter`.  `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is an annotation from Jackson.  Looking at your RestAdapter you don't seem to be specifying a Jackson Converter.

Square has implemented a JasksonConverter, you use it by including the dependency.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:X.X.X'
```

Use the version that matches your Retrofit version.

Then

```
JacksonConverter converter = JacksonConverter(new ObjectMapper());
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constant.URL_LOCALHOST)
            .setConverter(converter)
            .build();
```

Comment: Miguel your solution does not work.I had to make these changes: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.7.0' AND JacksonConverter converter = new JacksonConverter(new ObjectMapper());

Comment: I've updated my answer with your changes.  My apologies for the mistakes.  As far as I know you need to use the JasksonConverter if you want Retrofit to properly serialize/deserialize your JSON if Jackson is your main JSON tool.  Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with how to configure/use Jackson.